# Google Play Services uninstalled on my phone

Tags: google-play-services

I'm using a Blu Energy X Plus phone and somehow managed to uninstall Google Play Services. It can still be found in Apps, under 'All' although I can't access it. It needs updating but the last 3 digits after the dash of the older version i.e. Version 7.5.71 (1955121-...) are not visible so I'm not sure of the exact version to download.

The only options available now are 'Disable' & 'Force Stop'. Play Store is still on, but behaving erratically.Should I delete what's left? And how?

I don't want to compound the issue but I have no idea what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google play services cannot be openedby the user.and if your system *does* show it in all apps i doubt that its uninstalled! all you can do is update it which is automatically done overtime by the playstore